# Manual for php redirect() function

Tags: php

everybody,
I tried to google it, but unsuccessfully.
Many of php programmers use the redirect() function of php, but the official php documentation does not have description or any manuals for this function.
Can somebody give me the link to official page of this function?
Thanks in advance.
P.S. It is a function of Codeignitor an PHP framework.

Comment: That's because there is no `redirect()` function in PHP.

Comment: Questions that request an off-site resource are not allowed. Further, you answer your own question: "official php documentation does not have..."; "give me the link to official page of this [tag:php] function".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've only seen redirect() in php framework CodeIgniter, it uses php header().

Answer (score 3):

For many years I used a redirect function like below:

```
function redirect($url)
{
  if(headers_sent())
  {
    echo "<script>document.location.href='".$url."'</script>";
  }
  else
  {
    header("location: ".$url);
  }
}
```

Basically, the `header()` cannot be called if the output has already started. We test that using the `headers_sent()`. If we find that the headers have been sent then we use `JavaScript` to redirect, otherwise we use `PHP`

Answer (score 1):

The right name for redirect in PHP is header, I show you an example:

```
header("location: index.php");
```

link:
http://php.net/manual/it/function.header.php

Enjoy your code!